npm install command fails with EEXIST error
I am trying to run npm install command for my project but it fails with below errors:
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\be85dee9
npm ERR! errno -4075
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, open 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\be85dee9'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\be85dee9
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

I double checked and the file with that name doesn't even exist in that location.
Note: I am running VSCode with Admin privilege. Also tried with PS with Admin privilege.
Below is how my package.json looks like:
{
  "name": "@prjectname/test-angular",
  "version": "24.8.0",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.13.1",
    "npm": "^8.19.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "validate": "node ./security/anchor-validator.js && npm run lint && npm run lint-style && npm run test:ci",
    "build:dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
    "serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build:aot": "node --max_old_space_size=8096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --configuration production",
    "build:prod": "npm install && npm run build:aot",
    "build:console": "ng build --watch --output-path=\"%ProjectName%\\Console\\Web\\src\\Namespace\\Scripts\\AstroAir\\dist\"",
    "build:local": "ng build --source-map=true --output-path=\"C:\\stash\\ProjectName\\Console\\Web\\src\\WebSln\\Namespace\\Scripts\\AstroAir\\dist\"",
    "cleanup.bamboo": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/cleanup_bamboo.sh",
    "bamboo:validate": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/run_validate.sh",
    "bamboo:audit": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/run_audit.sh",
    "bamboo:run:e2e": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/run_e2e.sh",
    "bamboo:cleanup:e2e": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/cleanup_e2e.sh",
    "bamboo:build:aot": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/build_aot.sh",
    "webdriver:clean": "webdriver-manager clean",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update --chrome --ie --gecko",
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start --detach",
    "webdriver:stop": "webdriver-manager shutdown",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "e2e:fake": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 e2e/fake-api-server/fakerest.js",
    "e2e:console": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 e2e/console-server/server.js",
    "e2e:test:debug": "codeceptjs.cmd run --grep @smoke1 -R mocha-multi --verbose --debug",
    "e2e:test:smoke": "codeceptjs.cmd run -R mocha-multi --verbose --debug",
    "e2e:test:nonsmoke": "codeceptjs.cmd run --grep @smoke --invert -R mocha-multi --verbose --debug",
    "e2e:test": "codeceptjs.cmd run-multiple parallel -R reporter.js --verbose --debug",
    "clean:aw-ks/node_modules": "npm run rimraf -- node_modules/@projectname/kaleidoscope/node_modules",
    "test:ci": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --karma-config=karma.conf.ci.js --code-coverage=true --source-map=true",
    "lint": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng lint",
    "lint-style": "stylelint \"app/**/*.scss\"",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "rmrf": "./node_modules/.bin/rimraf.cmd dist",
    "compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p tsconfig.json",
    "serve.compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -s --port 9090",
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=4096 increase-memory-limit",
    "test:dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test",
    "pact:generate": "npm run pact:generate:dev",
    "pact:generate:dev": "jest --config jest.config.mjs --colors",
    "pact:generate:ci": "jest --config jest.config.mjs --colors --json --outputFile=logs\\pact.log",
    "pact:publish": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./bamboo/pact/publish.js",
    "pact:ci": "sh ./bamboo/scripts/run_pact_test.sh",
    "pact:verification": "node ./node_modules/wso-pact-verifier ./pacts 'replace it with path projectname dir where API specs are kept' --verbose",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://stash.projectname.com/sco/aa/reponame.git"
  },
  "config": {
    "pact_do_not_track": true
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://build-artifactory.domain.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/upgrade": "15.2.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^4.1.1",
    "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "16.0.1",
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "3.4.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.2.0",
    "@ngrx/data": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^15.4.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@open-amt-cloud-toolkit/ui-toolkit": "~2.0.8",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/angular": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.13",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.13",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.2",
    "@types/pako": "^1.0.3",
    "@uem/freestyle": "24.8.458",
    "@uem/kaleidoscope": "24.8.102",
    "@uem/wso-pact-verifier": "^1.23.0",
    "@uem/wso-utils-form-utils": "^24.2.0",
    "@uem/wso-utils-json-mapper": "^24.2.0",
    "@uem/wso-utils-localization": "^24.2.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^1.0.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.65.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.4",
    "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
    "js-sha256": "0.9.0",
    "jsonpath": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lottie-web": "^5.9.2",
    "lz-string": "^1.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.25.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-lottie": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-window-token": "^1.0.2",
    "pino-pretty": "^10.2.0",
    "polyfill-object.fromentries": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "rxjs": "^7.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "15.2.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@cds/core": "6.4.3",
    "@clr/angular": "15.5.1",
    "@clr/icons": "13.0.2",
    "@clr/ui": "15.5.1",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.16",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^15.4.0",
    "@nrwl/jest": "^16.6.0",
    "@pact-foundation/pact": "^10.4.1",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
    "@types/handlebars": "4.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "7.0.7",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.30",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.43.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "codeceptjs": "3.0.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "express-session": "1.15.6",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.7",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.1",
    "json-server": "^0.17.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.12",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-parallel": "^0.3.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "less": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "mocha-multi": "^1.1.3",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "npm-shrinkwrap": "6.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "rosie": "1.6.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.34.8",
    "session-file-store": "^1.3.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
    "stylelint-declaration-use-variable": "1.7.3",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.21.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint-jsdoc-rules": "0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webdriverio": "^6.7.1",
    "yargs": "^17.2.1"
  }
}

Things I have tried:

Did a clean installation for nvm (and node)
deleted entire npm-cache folder and ran with --force command
tried to clone my repo freshly and ran the npm install there
I have tried with different versions of node using nvm (node v20.9.0, v12.11, v22.6 etc)


make sure you have node v16.13.1 and npm v8.19.4 as you mentioned in package.json
